# Basis of subgroup of a free abelian group

Tags: free-abelian-group

We have this theorem:

** Let $F$ be a free abelian group of rank $n$ and let $H$ be a subgroup
of $F.$  There exists a basis $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ of $F$ and integers $d_1,...,d_r > 0 $ such
that

• $di\vert d_{i+1}$ for $i = 1,...,r$

• $\{d_1x_1,\ldots,d_rx_r\}$ is a basis of H.**

> I am confused with this.  $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ is a free abelian group with basis $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  Let $H=2\mathbb{Z}*3\mathbb{Z}$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ with basis $2(1,0)$ and $3(0,1)$.  $\mathbf {But}$ $2$ does not divide $3$.  What is the problem here?

Comment: i searched it many times but did't get my answer.can anybody help me?

Comment: The theorem doesn't say that **any** basis of $\;H\;$ will fulfill that. It only says that *some basis* **exists** such that...etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio can you tell me such basis of H?

Comment: May I ask where this theorem comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, take $\;B:=\{\,(2,3)\,,\,(1,2)\,\}\;$ , then show:

1) $\;B\;$ is a $\,\Bbb Z\,-$ linearly independent set and is thus a basis of $\;\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\;$ ;

2) $\;C:=\left\{\,1\cdot(2,3)\,,\,6\cdot(1,2)\,\}=\{\,(2,3)\,,\,\,(6,12)\,\right\}\;$ are $\;\Bbb Z\,-$ linearly independent and a basis of $\;2\Bbb Z\times3\Bbb Z\;$ as required.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my idea about this theorem